# Using callback in another callback in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm trying to another function after a function using call back in Jquery. 
but i don't know why the second function doesn't work, it doesn't seem that i have any typo or something in my code can you help me out of this problem?

here is my code. Thank you !

```
$("#best_1").animate({'opacity':'0'},2000, function(){
  $("#best_1").removeClass("best_1", function(){
    $("#best_1").animate({'opacity':'1'},2000);
    $("#best_1").addClass("best_11");

  });
});
```

Comment: There is no callback in `.removeClass()`; Is `best_1` a class or an id? Show your HTML markup.

Comment: Thank you for your anwert Louys, best_1 is class i'm using same name for id and class 

this is HTML markup for the part. 


<div id="best_1" class="best_1 best_img">

   <span class="be_date">Date 2018</span>
   <span class="be_title">Contents</span>
   <span class="be_button">Check</span>

  </div>


how should i do to make another callback function within a callback function?

Comment: I made an answer for you... Hoping that will help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`removeClass` is synchronous

Try

```
$("#best_1").animate({'opacity':'0'},2000, function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("best_1 best_11 ").animate({'opacity':'1'},2000);     
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your wonderful answer ! it made things much easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to use a callback to have a particular order of execution... Which I don't now.

But here is what I think you want:

```
$("#best_1").animate({'opacity':'0'},2000, function(){   // Executes 1st
  $("#best_1").removeClass("best_1");                    // Executes 2nd
  $("#best_1").animate({'opacity':'1'},2000, function(){ // Executes 3rd
    $("#best_1").addClass("best_11");                    // Executes 4th
  });
});
```

This way, the lines #2,3 and 4 are inside the 1st callback, which occurs after the fisrt animation; And line #4 is in the callback of the second [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) on line #3.

Some methods allow the use of a callback to be executed after something... But most methods do not. in those cases, you can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to delay the execution of something.

I don't have your CSS... So I invented some for the below example.

About `setTimeout()`, its order of execution would be right after the first animate... Before it has finished the animation. The 5 seconds delay starts right after the "reading" of the first line. So it is 5 seconds from the start... Not from the end of the last animation.

```js
$("#best_1").animate({'opacity':'0'},2000, function(){   // Executes 1st
  $("#best_1").removeClass("best_1");                    // Executes 2nd
  $("#best_1").animate({'opacity':'1'},2000, function(){ // Executes 3rd
    $("#best_1").addClass("best_11");                    // Executes 4th
  });
});
setTimeout(function(){
  $(".be_title").html("Hello! I appeared after 5 seconds because of setTimeout.")
},5000);
```

```css
.best_1{
  color:red;
}
.best_11{
  color:blue;
}
.be_date{
  display:block;
}
.be_title{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:2em;
}
.be_button{
  display:block;
  width:3em;
  background-color:grey;
  border-radius:6px;
  padding:0.5em 1em;
  margin:0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="best_1" class="best_1 best_img">
  <span class="be_date">Date 2018</span>
  <span class="be_title">Contents</span>
  <span class="be_button">Check</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and long explanation! i could finally solve my problem thanks to you Louys ! hope you will have an wonderful day and happy new year :)

Comment: Happy new year to you too! ;)